# The son of Mrs. 11 and Mr. 17

Tags: riddle

> I am an important person for my kinds,
>   Do you remember when you walked 1267200 feet with me so that you could defiance,
>   I used to save things a lot but you don't use me anymore because you have got a cool guy,
>   My mom is Mrs 11 and dad is Mr 17 but their relationship is weak and if it's broken then I will die.
>   Can you guess who am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're

> Salt

Because

I am an important person for my kinds,

> Used in vegetables. The most important in all of the seasonings.

Do you remember when you walked 1267200 feet with me so that you could defiance,

> Gandhi's salt march, 240 miles = 1267200 feet. He walked for the Non-cooperation movement.

I used to save things a lot but you don't use me anymore because you have got a cool guy,

> People used to store a lot of things in salt, before the refrigerator made that obsolete.

My mom is Mrs 11 and dad is Mr 17 but their relationship is weak and if it's broken then I will die.

> Periodic table, 11 = Na, 17 = Cl, Salt is NaCl, if their bond breaks you're just left with ions.

Comment: was it that easy?

Comment: @manshu the 11 and 17 hint was to easy Yup :) But i learned something about Gandhi at least :D

Comment: I there some specific reason why `spoiler1` is mother (Mrs) and `spoiler2` is father (Mr), not the opposite? Or did @manshu just assigned genders randomly?

Comment: @sasha could be that he's a feminist :P, natrium ions are positive and chloride ions are negative :) But i'm guessing it was random

Comment: i assigned them randomly. In fact I first wrote Mr 11 and Mrs 17 in title and Mrs 11 and Mr 17 in question and had to change one of them for consistency.

Comment: @DrunkWolf, your last comment is sample case that illustrates, why we may need spoiler tags in comments too

Comment: @Sasha No we dont need it. If the reader is solving the puzzle on his/her own then he wont scroll down.

Comment: @manshu, and what if he has a cat on keyboard? :)

Comment: @manshu, I'm sorry

Comment: @manshu, Thanks for your answer about genders – I just was interested whether such association exists in some culture.